# General FizzBuzz in Java

Tags: java, fizzbuzz

I have this generalization of FizzBuzz in Java:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class GeneralFizzBuzz {

    public static void generalFizzBuzz(Map<Integer, String> map, 
                                       int start, 
                                       int stop) {
        String startString = String.valueOf(start);
        String stopString = String.valueOf(stop);

        // Find the width which can accommodate any line number:
        int lineNumberWidth = Math.max(startString.length(), 
                                       stopString.length());

        // Create the format string for printing line numbers:
        String lineNumberFormat = "%" + lineNumberWidth + "d: ";

        for (int i = start; i <= stop; ++i) {
            // Print the line number and the colon with a space:
            System.out.printf(lineNumberFormat, i);

            for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                if (i % entry.getKey() == 0) {
                    System.out.print(entry.getValue());
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

        map.put(2, "Foo");
        map.put(7, "Bar");
        map.put(11, "Baz");

        generalFizzBuzz(map, -200, 200);
    }

}
```

As always, please tell me whatever comes to mind.

Comment: Where are the unit tests? How do you plan to unit test a method that is `void` and prints to the console? If you're not writing unit tests when coding, then that is the **first** thing to fix.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm... the generalFizzBuzz method is a mix of business logic and output, I think this should rather be separeted.

Thus, I'd rather have a business logic conversion number, which converts a given number to test to the output string:

```
private static String convertNumberForOutput(Map<Integer, String> numberReplacement, int num) {
    // not necessarily better than a loop, but to show a different approach
    // (attn: I have not tried to compile this ;-))
    return numberReplacement.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> (num % e.getKey()) == 0)
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

In the generalFizzBuzz method, replace the inner loop with a call to that function.

Naming: "map" is a no-go-name. This is like calling start and stop "numberA" and "numberB". The map has a logical purpose, so you should reflect this in its naming.

Answer (score 1):

#### Comments

Comments should only be used to tell **why** the code is like it is.

Your comments are different, they somewhat split the method into parts. Therefore you should rather create methods named after the comments:

```
public static void generalFizzBuzz(Map<Integer, String> map, 
                                   int start, 
                                   int stop) {
    String startString = String.valueOf(start);
    String stopString = String.valueOf(stop);
    int lineNumberWidth = findWidthAccommodatingAnyLineNumber(startString, stopString);
    String lineNumberFormat = createFormatStringForLineNumbers(lineNumberWidth);
    for (int i = start; i <= stop; ++i) {
        printLineNumberUsing(lineNumberFormat, i);
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (i % entry.getKey() == 0) {
                System.out.print(entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
private static void printLineNumberUsing(String lineNumberFormat, int i){         
    System.out.printf(lineNumberFormat, i);
}
private static int findWidthAccommodatingAnyLineNumber(String startString, STring stopString){
    return Math.max(startString.length(), stopString.length());
}
private static String createFormatStringForLineNumbers(int lineNumberWidth){
     return "%" + lineNumberWidth + "d: ";
}
```

#### Naming

Your method is called `generalFizzBuzz` which is not starting with a *verb*. Methods schould always start with a verb or at least express an action.

#### Visibility scopes

Your method has the `public` scope modifier. But since there is currently no other class using it it should have `private` visibility scope.

#### Correctness

Your code fails to solve the game because the rules are to output **either** current number **or** the word, not both.

Answer (score 0):

It is all static.

It's not bad *per se*, but why not **use the notion of Object** ?

You could make `GeneralFizzBuzz` an Object that holds parameterizable the rules, and presents a method to apply those rules to a range. As it is, you've put the user on a position where he/she has to know that you represent the fizzbuzz rules as a Map. This is unnecessary.

Have a look at this *stateful* FizzBuzz (without changing anything else):

```
public class GeneralFizzBuzz {

    private final Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void addRule(int targetNumber, String output){
        map.put(targetNumber, output);
    }

    public void fizzBuzz(int start, int stop) {
        String startString = String.valueOf(start);
        String stopString = String.valueOf(stop);

        // Find the width which can accommodate any line number:
        int lineNumberWidth = Math.max(startString.length(), 
                                       stopString.length());

        // Create the format string for printing line numbers:
        String lineNumberFormat = "%" + lineNumberWidth + "d: ";

        for (int i = start; i <= stop; ++i) {
            // Print the line number and the colon with a space:
            System.out.printf(lineNumberFormat, i);

            for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                if (i % entry.getKey() == 0) {
                    System.out.print(entry.getValue());
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GeneralFizzBuzz gfb = new GeneralFizzBuzz();

        gfb.addRule(2, "Foo");
        gfb.addRule(7, "Bar");
        gfb.addRule(11, "Baz");

        gfb.gizzBuzz(-200, 200);
    }
}
```

I think this is easier to use, less prone to mistakes, etc.